# Export a jar file from Eclipse or Command Line

Tags: jar, manifest

This is my first post ever but I intend to use this more often in the future so please be critical if I do something wrong.

I have done research on the topic and have already attempted everything from using the command line to Eclipse's File>export>jar and choosing the appropriate options.

Basically I have attempted everything suggested in the following two links:

[Java: export to an .jar file in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423938/java-export-to-an-jar-file-in-eclipse)

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/basicsindex.html

The results of my efforts are:
1) a jar file is created
2) when I try to run it the error is "Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from test.jar"

I assure you that I have indeed created a "manifest.txt" file in my project that consists of 
"Main-Class: Login
"
I even include a newline because I hear that is necessary in some instances.

Does anyone know what I could be missing? Or better yet can anyone please provide an extremely detailed explanation of how to create a jar. This could be either from command line or eclipse.

My current project is setup where I have three java files in my workspace: Login, NewFrame, and NewUser. Login has the main method which will eventually call the other files. These three files are in the default package. The projects name is JavaVersion.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the jar file please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Antimony for your interest and help. After more tinkering I was able to figure it out for myself. Turns out I was never correctly defining the entry point. For anyone looking to export a jar in Eclipse I would also like to recommend this link.

[How do you build a JAR in eclipse with a custom manifest file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106467/how-do-you-build-a-jar-in-eclipse-with-a-custom-manifest-file?rq=1)